# jumbotron background image doesn't show

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, background

I want to show the image in the background but it doesn't show:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid background: url('/assets/img/mhacks.jpg') no-repeat center center;">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-t-3">

        <h1 class="display-2">Mona Jalal</h1>
        <p class="lead">Under construction</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I see is:
[image]

P.S.: In general how can I debug such faults?
Here's my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e5qsnjdo/

With the following code:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid style="background-image: url('/assets/img/mhacks.jpg') no-repeat center center;">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-t-3">

        <h1 class="display-2">Mona Jalal</h1>
        <p class="lead">Under construction</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get these errors:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `background` property to `style` attribute:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background: url('/assets/img/mhacks.jpg') no-repeat center center;">
```

Or define in css as follows:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('./assets/img/mhacks.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

// notice the . before /assets if you don't use the . it will give the 404 error -

Comment: I get the error, namespace background is not bound. Why is that?

Comment: @Mona Can you make a fiddle for your problem as the error you described is a bit strange?

Comment: can you please be a little more clear on what is problematic? I have also updated the question.

Comment: @Mona it should be `class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="..."` but you have in code `class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid style="`... Notice the missing quotes after `jumbotron-fluid`

Comment: can you please browse to http://monajalal.github.io/ I wonder why the navbar is covering the jumbotron?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114716/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-mona-jalal).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style=" background: url('/assets/img/mhacks.jpg') no-repeat center center;">
    <div class="container text-sm-center p-t-3">

        <h1 class="display-2">Mona Jalal</h1>
        <p class="lead">Under construction</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this : change your CSS properties from background to background-image.

e.g. background-image: url("/assets/img/mhacks.jpg" ) cover no-repeat;