# Jumbotron background doesn't show with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I'm using Bootstrap with template engine Thymeleaf for the front end, however I can't seem to get the background image to show with my inline CSS, I tried the answer in this stackoverflow question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831281/4465028), here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Jumbotron</title>

</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="jumbotron" >

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid"  style=" background-image: url('/static/jumbotron1.jpg'); text-align: center; margin-top: 110px;" >
  <h1>Bonjour</h1>
  <p> Application architectural</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Apprendre</a></p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The most important line here is: `background-image: url('/static/jumbotron1.jpg');` 
Here's how my files are lined up with (Jumbotron1.jpg being the image):

[image: files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add static resources to thymeleaf using the @{} syntax.

```
<div th:style="'background:url(' + @{/<path-to-image>} + ');'"></div>
```

in your case  , you have to test with this two option :

```
<div th:style="'background:url(' + @{/static/jumbotron1.jpg} + '); text-align: center; margin-top: 110px;'"></div>
```

or :

```
<div th:style="'background:url(' + @{/jumbotron1.jpg} + '); text-align: center; margin-top: 110px; '"></div>
```

Comment: what if you use only : 
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid"  style=" background-image: url('/jumbotron1.jpg'); text-align: center; margin-top: 110px;" >